# Remove reveal effect on click

Tags: android, onclick, android-5.0-lollipop, circularreveal

In my application I am using a ListView CheckedTextView.
When you run the app on a device lollipop when I click on the CheckedTextView the reveal effect is shown, the default reveal effect included in lollipop.

My intention is that when you click on the CheckedTextView, the effect reveal not apply.

Is there any way to remove this?

Thanks in advance and greetings.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding this attribute to your `CheckedTextView`:

```
android:stateListAnimator="@null"
```